# Refreshing a listbox in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a listbox with some images .I just want refresh listbox after clicking refresh button when an item is added.
Here is my code.

```
   public class img
    {
        public BitmapImage Imgs { get; set; }
    }


public void getImages()
    {
        try
        {
            MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
            var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
            foreach (var picture in pictures)
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());
                img mediaImage = new img();
                mediaImage.Imgs = image;
                imageList.Items.Add(mediaImage);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

after clicking refresh button iam calling get images() ,but its not working...
is it possible with out observable collection.
here is my xaml==

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="Sc" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="550" >
           <ListBox Name="imageList" Height="617"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}" SelectionChanged="imageList_SelectionChanged" >

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>
                          <Image Source="{Binding Imgs}" Width="100" Height="100"/>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you try to refresh the listbox you are invoking getImages() method which will still add the list again along with the existing list. This will create a duplicate items in list box.

The best solution to update the list box when ever you do an refresh is to Bind the collection to the Listbox.ItemSource. In case if you not wanted to use Observable collection and INotifyProperty Changed interface, You should at least set the collection to ListBox.ItemSource when ever you refresh the data from code behind.

Code snippet:

```
 MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
 var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;

List<img> Images = new List<img>();

            foreach (var picture in pictures)
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());
                img mediaImage = new img();
                mediaImage.Imgs = image;
                Images.Items.Add(mediaImage);
            }
imageList.ItemsSource = Images;
```

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue. Please mark as answer if it resolves your issue.

Thanks,
Kamal.

Comment: thanks for replying brother,but when iam refreshing it is saying item source must be empty(exception)